# Xcode breakpoint triggers despite wrapping if case being false

Tags: xcode, ios, debugging, xcode4, breakpoints

Hard to put in words, so here is an screen of this in action:
[image]

As the text says, it "stopped at breakpoint". The problem is, that if case is false. It shouldn't break, since the breakpoint is within the if case.

I tried putting the int a = 1; and a = 2 around the BriefLog (which is a NSLog style macro) as sometimes it gets confused about lines, but no luck. Any idea what's up with this? Making debugging really hard cause this method is called quite a lot. :(

Comment: Which compiler are you using , LLVM GCC can be flakier than LLVM2.

Comment: That is the one I'm using, I believe. Should I use LLVM2? Is it stable enough for production dev? I somehow presumed it wasn't.

Comment: I haven't really looked at it. Though dominant opinion seems that LLVM2 isn't good enough for prod yet. Im using LLVM2 for dev and seems OK to me. Fussier compiler.

Comment: Hm, that's not very good news, I guess. I'll run on LLVM2 for awhile and see if I or any testers run into new fun bugs.

Comment: @Warren Burton: Sorry for the late response, but that seems to have fixed it, actually. Hate to go beta on myself, but if it's what Apple intends people to migrate to eventually, it can only get better over time. Mind posting that as an answer, so I can accept?

Comment: Turns out LLVM 2 isn't so bad . it was the LLVM 1.x ones I was thinking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using LLVM2 rather than LLVM GCC.

If your project came from XCode3 especially your compiler may be set at the latter.

The debugger in LLVM GCC code can have a 'personality'.

LLVM2 has a fussier compiler but it's a good thing and the debugging seems to be a lot more stable especially if you use LLDB with OS X projects.

Less non-visited breakpoints and odd non-workingness.

Answer (score 0):

Its Xcode 4's fault. Debugging of ObjC code is just like playing Poker at a pro table without knowing the rules. File a bug and hope that Xcode 4.1 comes soon and fixes it.

Comment: I figured as much, but mostly wondering if there's a workaround, like doing a clean or tweaking some optimization setting or such.

Comment: I'm afraid that nothing will help in this case.